# Force a 404 error when ".php" is present in URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess code which **hides** the .php extension. It works wonders.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php
```

I'm now attempting to produce a 404 Not Found error when .php is present in the URL, because I want to force people to use URLs without .php. Here's the code I have now:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ /home.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php - [L,R=404]
```

I am a complete newbie to .htaccess but the code above is causing a 404 error whenever I go to a .php page, even if .php is not in the URL.

What adjustments must I make in order to make it only cause a 404 Not Found when .php is in the URL?

Comment: A .htaccess style file can never "hide" something. It only works on _incoming_ requests. It is up to the page you send out what is visible inside the URLs. If you don't send out URLs containing a .php suffix, then where is the problem? Why do you want to block other URLs? Just forward them and everyone is happy! Otherwise you frustrate users.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite conditions only apply to the *immediately following* rule, which means:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

only gets applied to

```
RewriteRule ^$ /home.php [QSA,L]
```

but not the rule that follows that:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php - [L,R=404]
```

The problem with this last rule is that it checks if the URI has a `.php` in it, which it **will** because you're adding the `.php` extension in your first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php
```

So you need to add another condition to prevent that from happening:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ /home.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+[^\?\ ]+\.php
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```